# What happens in Apache Ignite when a client gets disconnected?

Tags: java, ignite

We use Apache Ignite for caching and are seeing some unexpected behavior across all of the clients of cluster when one of the clients fails. The Ignite cluster itself has three servers and there are approximately 12 servers connecting to that cluster as clients. The cluster has persistence disabled and many of the caches have near caching enabled.

What we are seeing is that when one of the clients fail (out of memory, high CPU, network connectivity, etc.), threads on all the other clients block for a period of time.  During these times, the Ignite servers themselves seem fine but I see things like the following in the logs:

```
Topology snapshot [ver=123, servers=3, clients=11, CPUs=XXX, offheap=XX.XGB, heap=XXX.GB]
Topology snapshot [ver=124, servers=3, clients=10, CPUs=XXX, offheap=XX.XGB, heap=XXX.GB]
```

The topology itself is clearly changing when a client connects/disconnects but is there anything happening internally inside the cluster that could cause blocking on other clients? I would expect re-balancing of data when a server disconnects but not a client.

From a thread dump, I see many threads stuck in the following state:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x000000078a86ff18> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.await(IgniteUtils.java:7452)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.awaitAllReplies(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:1056)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.query(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:733)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$8.iterator(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1339)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.QueryCursorImpl.iterator(QueryCursorImpl.java:95)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$9.iterator(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1403)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.QueryCursorImpl.iterator(QueryCursorImpl.java:95)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
...
```

Any ideas, suggestions, or further avenues to investigate would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Ignite do you use?

Comment: When topology changes, partition map exchange is triggered internally. It blocks all operations on the cluster. Also in old versions ongoing rebalancing was cancelled. But in the latest versions client connection/disconnection doesn't affect some processes like this. So, it's worth trying the most fresh release.

Comment: Topology snapshot version (124) don't look good. Please close all the running Ignite instances, and try again.

Comment: @Denis - We are using version 2.4. Do you know what version the change was made that prevents client connect/disconnect from triggering a rebalance?

Comment: @AshishBhosle - We deploy fairly frequently so its very common for our Ignite client applications to be restarted.  If the client connecting and disconnecting creates a new topology version, a large version number seems expected.

Comment: @nolt2232 I was referring to the following fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7165 It's been fixed in version 2.7